# Adobe Creative Cloud "Updates" available?

Tags: updates, adobe-creative-cloud, saas

I have some licensed Adobe apps on my computer, CS6 and Acrobat 11, which apparently installed "Adobe Creative Cloud" 3.8.something. Recently CC has been helpfully informing me that I have updates available. It wants to update Acrobat to "Latest Version" Acrobat DC, and make unclear changes to "Previous Version" CS6 apps.

In my old-school nerd terminology, "update" means an incremental version increase that's offered free of charge, as opposed to an "upgrade" that requires additional payment. But I'm concerned that when Adobe CC says "update", they actually mean "**pay us a yearly tithe forever**". Is that correct?

Comment: "something from Creative Cloud" please edit your to provide specifics

Answer (score 0):

So I bit the bullet and used Adobe CC to update my CS6 apps. They were just standard CS6 point updates. So the "Previous Versions" section is safe enough.

But I'm not touching Acrobat DC without more info.